# show another xml by clicking a button without creating another activity

Tags: java, android, xml

Is there any way to avoid creating another activity to show an xml page from another xml by clicking a button.
The same activity must be used instead of creating another one in this case.

Comment: You should check out `Fragments`

Comment: i don't know why devote. is this unclear non grammer peace of shit. if not clear how can someone answer the question

Answer (score 0):

You can inflate your XML View to one of your Layout in Activity's xml Layout file. 
1. Create Blank RelativeLayout and set visibility invisible. 
2. On your action performed set Visibility true and inflate view to Relative layout like below code.

```
RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.item);
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child, null);
item.addView(child);
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Android world , check this out
[Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)